# Bash script append variable to file

Tags: bash, scripts

I just created bash script and want to append the variable script, but it was not working properly, and here is the script :

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

I tried to run append this script using echo but the results is not the same:

```
echo "export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'" > wew.txt
```

if we `cat wew.txt` the result was :

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=0;logger -p local6.debug widianto [69]: echo "export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'" > wew.txt []'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

What you're observing here is that 'strong quotes' lose their strength when wrapped in "weak quotes":

```
$ echo $foo
bar
$ echo '$foo'
$foo
$ echo "echo '$foo'"
echo 'bar'
```

Although you could fix your code by backslash-escaping every special character, a better way to avoid expansion by the shell might be to use a here-document instead of an `echo`, and quote (in *any* of the supported ways - weak, strong or backslash) the end marker:

```
$ cat << \EOF
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
EOF

export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have succesfully with created variable :

```
widianto@rancher3:~$ cat b.bash
#!/bin/bash
# widianto

a="export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug"
b='"$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed'
c='"s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'


echo "$a $b $c'" >> /home/widianto/test.txt
```

Thank you